# How to migrate an API Gateway with a custom domain name to another AWS account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have an API gateway with a custom domain name (`foo.mycompany.com`).

`foo.mycompany.com` belongs to the production environment, i.e., there is traffic coming from the customers of the service almost every minute.

How can I migrate `foo.mycompany.com` to another AWS account without causing any downtime for the service?

When I create the `foo.mycompany.com` custom domain name in the AWS console of the new AWS account, I got `The domain name you provided already exists.` error.

[image]

Comment: if possible use API gateway end point which generally provided by AWS like XXXXXX.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/stage in your code and then you chance. Downtime will be there. These way you can avoid downtime.

Comment: As a partial workaround, to keep the domain name in the old account while moving other resources to the new one, you might remap the custom domain to a new "proxy" API in the old account which uses an HTTP integration to route all requests to the API in the new account (not using a custom domain). However I'm still testing this right now and there might be increased latency and other issues.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately it is not possible at the moment. I run a couple of API GW for high load clients and all had the same issue when migrating to new AWS accounts. We even reached to AWS specialists. The answer was :

1. Delete custom domain name in OLD account
2. Add custom domain in new account

This of course means downtime.
If someone else finds a blue-green migration possibility for these - I would like to know too.

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly if you move to different region.
The flow I used was

- switch api domain to edge
- create infrastructure in another region
- switch DNS to that other region - custom domain was already created there.

Unfortunately, custom API domain has to be unique in a region.

I am in similar situation as you now and I am trying to figure out solution.

**2023 update:**

AWS now supports wildcard api domains:
https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/10/api-gateway-supports-wildcard-custom-domain-names/

You need to ask AWS support for exception (and in my case it took 3 weeks!) but eventually you will create `*.mycompany.com` on new account and it will handle traffic. When migrated, you can kill api gateway on old account and simply create `foo.mycompany.com` on new one.

Comment: Maybe this works? https://medium.com/@spei/migrating-an-amazon-api-gateway-with-a-custom-domain-with-no-downtime-f33942beef1e

Answer (score 0):

You can use a step-Region to create the same custom domain name and migrate the APIG there first, and then back to the original region on a different account.
Like region1-account1 -> region2-account1 -> region1-account2
For a complete solution, take a look here: https://medium.com/@spei/migrating-an-amazon-api-gateway-with-a-custom-domain-with-no-downtime-f33942beef1e